# cv2.VideoWriter with cap from video file

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

While saving a video file with `cv2`, I got a strange problem. This code works well if the video capture occurs from a webcam, but if the video capture occurs from a file (ex. `cap = cv2.VideoCapture("test.avi"`)), an empty file is formed without any stream.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, w)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, h)

out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), fps, (w, h))

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    out.write(frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break
            
out.release()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried changing the format of the input video files, such as `avi` and `ts`, as well as the output, but nothing changed.

Who knows why this problem happened to me?

Comment: You may take a look at the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61202978/how-to-explicitly-access-mjpeg-backend-for-videocapture-in-opencv/61208246#61208246). The first part of my answer generates a synthetic AVI video file. The second part captures frames from the created video file. **1.** Execute the code as is. **2.** Replace `cv2.CAP_OPENCV_MJPEG` with `cv2.CAP_FFMPEG`. **3.** Edit your post to capture frames from a file. **4.** I recommend you to include the part of building the synthetic video in your edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some time I figured out the problem. This part disturbs me to finalize the video:

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
   break
```

After I removed "break" all became normal. Maybe cuz, unlike the stream received from the camera, the stream from the video file is finite, and my interrupt prevented finalization.

Comment: You don't need to remove `break` here. You should add a check on `ret`. if `ret == False` exit from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try printing the cam.isOpened() output? Your available camera might be intitialized with a variable different than 0.

Try `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)`. Besides that, are you running this on Linux? Make sure you got ffmpeg installed.

Comment: I have no problem with writing from webcam, it works very good, I have problem with writing from file like this cv2.VideoCapture("test.avi"), of course imshow function shows frame pretty well.